# Trouble making my first PDF

Tags: pdf

I've been reading through the PDF spec for the past couple hours and this is what I've come up with. But it's not rendering in OSX Preview:

```
%PDF-1.3

1 0 obj
<< /Type /Catalog /Pages 2 0 R >>
endobj

2 0 obj
<< /Type /Pages /Kids [ 3 0 R ] /Count 1>>
endobj

3 0 obj
<< /Type /Page /Parent 2 0 R /Resources <<>> /MediaBox [0 0 500 500] /Contents 4 0 R >>
endobj

4 0 obj
BT
/F13 12 Tf (Hello World!) Tj 
ET
endobj

xref
0 5 
0000000000 65535 f
0000000010 00000 n
0000000059 00000 n
0000000119 00000 n
0000000221 00000 n

trailer 
<< /Size 5 /Root 1 0 R >>
startxref
267
%%EOF
```

I'm sure it's something with my text object, but I'm having trouble figuring it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few corrections, the following renders for me on xpdf 3.0

```
%PDF-1.3

1 0 obj
<< /Type /Catalog /Pages 2 0 R >>
endobj

2 0 obj
<< /Type /Pages /Kids [ 3 0 R ] /Count 1>>
endobj

3 0 obj
<< /Type /Page /Parent 2 0 R /Resources << /Font << /F13 5 0 R >> /MediaBox [0 0 500 500] >> /Contents 4 0 R >>
endobj

4 0 obj
<< /Length 46 >>
stream
BT
/F13 12 Tf 100 250 Td (Hello World!) Tj
ET
endstream
endobj

5 0 obj
<< /BaseFont /Helvetica /Encoding /MacRomanEncoding /Name /F13 /Subtype /Type1 /Type /Font >>
endobj

xref
0 6
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000010 00000 n 
0000000060 00000 n 
0000000119 00000 n 
0000000247 00000 n 
0000000343 00000 n 

trailer
<< /Size 6 /Root 1 0 R >>
startxref
453
%%EOF
```

Things, I needed to change:

- Added font object `5 0 R` for `/F13`
- Added `100 250 Td` to content stream. needed to set the current position
- Corrected format of `4 0 R`. Note the `<< /Length 46 >>` and `stream`, `endstream` markers.
- Corrections to `xref`. In particular first line `0000000000 65535 f` is a dummy free object. First real object appears as the second entry.

Comment: ***+1*** -- good job. *Almost* perfect -- but for flawlessness you'll have to change: `startxref` value isn't correct; `/Size` should be `4`; `/Length` should be `46`; maybe some items. But yes, it renders in XPDF and in Preview.app :-)

Comment: Oh, and the `xref` entries themselves: they need to be exactly 20 bytes long, including the EOL character. If it's a 2-byte EOL, you need one padding space at the end (after the `f` and `n`).

Comment: You can use **[QPDF](http://qpdf.sf.net/)** for a basic check of PDF syntax, stream lenghts and xref entries like this: `qpdf --check input.pdf`.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I was close. I assumed there was a default font I could get away with and that the current position would default to 0 0. It wasn't clear from the spec that the text object needed to be in a stream but maybe I just need to read it a little more carefully. But from the beginning of "BT" to the end of "ET" is 45 bytes... why should it be 46? Also, shouldn't the size be 6 (the # of entries in xref), according to the spec?

Comment: @Kurt thanks. lost xref padding during cut & paste to SO. Hopefully better now. Also adjusted /Size in trailer.

Comment: @user2320861: the last hard return after `ET` counts as well.

Comment: @user2320861: It's been too hard a day for me... I've made two mistakes: ***(1)*** `/Size` *was* already **`4`** -- should be **`5`** (your version of the file), of course.  -- ***(2)*** If it's a ***1***-byte EOL, you need to pad 1 space at the end (after **`f`** or **`n`**).

Comment: @dwarring: Had a typo in my comment, as you noticed: of course, your version of the file should have had **`/Size 6`** (as it now does). -- Yes, putting PDF source code into an SO answer interface is not so easy, given that trailing spaces, specific EOL characters (and binary contents) can easily get lost...